# Column or new table

Tags: database-design

I am working on a student management system for a private school. In the table "student" I need to indicate which public school the student came from. Can I just keep this information as a column "school" in the student table or do I need to make a new table "school"? **NB:** The school has just one attribute which is its name.

Comment: Another way of thinking about this: How are you going to make sure that no-one enters the same school using 2 different spellings? While making it a separate table with a foreign key won't stop this happening it will greatly reduce the incidence of this sort of "dirty data".

Answer (score 3):

I say you should create a table for Schools with a foreign key in Students pointing to the correct record in Schools.

A sample set of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Schools
(
    SchoolID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Schools PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , SchoolName nvarchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Students
(
    StudentID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Students PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1, 1)
    , SchoolID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Schools (SchoolID) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    , StudentName nvarchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Schools (SchoolName) VALUES ('MySchool');
INSERT INTO dbo.Schools (SchoolName) VALUES ('Some Other School');

SELECT * FROM dbo.Schools;

INSERT INTO dbo.Students (SchoolID, StudentName) VALUES (1, 'Some Student in MySchool');
INSERT INTO dbo.Students (SchoolID, StudentName) VALUES (1, 'Some other student in MySchool');
INSERT INTO dbo.Students (SchoolID, StudentName) VALUES (2, 'Some Student in Some Other School');
INSERT INTO dbo.Students (SchoolID, StudentName) VALUES (2, 'Some other student in Some Other School');
INSERT INTO dbo.Students (SchoolID, StudentName) VALUES (1, 'Another student in MySchool');

SELECT SchoolName, StudentName
FROM dbo.Schools
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Students ON Schools.SchoolID = Students.SchoolID;
```

And the results from this:

[image]

This allows an unlimited number of students, and an unlimited number of schools, and does not repeat the name of the School unnecessarily for students who went to the same school.  This saves space in the database, and makes querying students in a given school much faster.

Comment: Third normal form has to do with transitive dependencies. It has nothing to do with whether you store a school's name or its id number. (ID numbers have *nothing* to do with normalization.)

Answer (score 1):

Even though the school has only one attribute (it's name), I would still recommend a second table with the school name, and an ID. The situation where this will help you is when someone discovers that a school name referenced by many students is not spelled correctly, and needs to be corrected. In this case, you just update one record in the `schools` table with the correct spelling. The other option would be to update all rows that have the incorrect spelling. This might not seem like a terrible thing, but if there's enough data in your database, it can slow things down quite a bit.

Having the second table will also give you flexibility in the future in case it is decided that your system needs more than just the school name.